# While there are 2 separate click listeners it seems both are clicking at the same time. why?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a To Do List with javascript. I want a code to delete a task when button is clicked and check the task done when the task itself is clicked. so far I've written the code below.But my problem is that when I add tasks to the list and then I want to delete, some error happens. Supposedly because both delete and the task itself are clicked. Since I've added 2 seperate onclick listeners for them, I cannot understand why both of them are clicked?
here is my js code:

```
let newTask = document.getElementById('new-task');
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
let deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');

let incompleteTaskHolder=document.getElementById('incomplete-tasks');//ul of #incomplete-tasks
let completedTasksHolder=document.getElementById('completed-tasks');    
function createNewItem(name){

    //creat a new element to the list
    let newItem = document.createElement("li");
    
    //label
    let label=document.createElement("label");//label
    label.innerText=name;
    //button.delete
    let deleteButton=document.createElement("button");//delete button
    deleteButton.innerText="Delete";
    deleteButton.className="delete";
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        newItem.style.display = 'none';
        newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
}, false);

    //attaching element to the page
    newItem.appendChild(label);
    newItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    incompleteTaskHolder.appendChild(newItem);

    return newItem;
}


addButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    newTaskName = newTask.value;
    newItem = createNewItem(newTaskName);
    
    newItem.addEventListener('click',function(){
        
        //Check tasks as done
        let ul = newItem.parentNode;
        ul.removeChild(newItem);
        newItem.style.display = 'none';
        
        newItem.style.display ='block';
        completedTasksHolder.appendChild(newItem);
    });

    newTask.value = '';
});

/*DELETE for already written tasks*/
for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length ; i++) {
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log("Delete Task...");
        let listItem = this.parentNode;
        let ul = listItem.parentNode;
        //Remove the parent list item from the ul.
        listItem.style.display = 'none';
        ul.removeChild(listItem);
    });
}
```

here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <label for="new-task">Add Item</label><input id="new-task" type="text"><button id='add-btn'>Add</button>
  </p>
  
  <h3>Todo</h3>
  <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
    <li><label>Pay Bills</label><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li class="editMode"><label>Go Shopping</label><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    
  </ul>
  
  <h3>Completed</h3>
  <ul id="completed-tasks">
    <li><label>See the Doctor</label><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please post the error you are facing

Comment: here is the error : script.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (script.js:44)

Comment: You are adding a click event to a li and a click event for the button in the li. Clicking on the delete button should fire the delete button function and the li function. Events 101, clicking on a chlld fires events up the tree.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example for you to help understand [Event Propagation and Event Bubbling.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

What is happening here is that when you click on the button, the event will also "propagate" to its container, or in this case the `li` element the button is inside of.

In order to stop this from happening, you have to call the `stopPropagation()` method on the event first thing in the handler function:

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // first we make sure that this event will not propagate to the parent,
    // because we have a different handle for it
    e.stopPropagation();
    newItem.style.display = 'none';
    newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
}, false);
```

Here's also some things you should look into for cleaner, more maintainable code:

- [Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)
- Refactor your code in such a way as to avoid nesting the event listener registration

Have fun!